# Simplificar multiples "else if" basados en el valor de una variable string

Tags: javascript, revisión-de-código

El siguiente código  funciona y tiene 4 condiciones pero quiero simplificarlo ya que son en realidad 150 condiciones, ¿ habrá alguna  otra manera de reducir este algoritmo y que no sean 150 else if?

```
for (var j = 0; j < $scope.cants.length; j++) {
  if ($scope.cants[j].type === "bases") {       
    $scope.bases += $scope.cants[j].quantity;
  } else if ($scope.cants[j].type === "proteins") {     
    $scope.proteins += $scope.cants[j].quantity;
  } else if ($scope.cants[j].type === "veggies") {      
    $scope.veggies += $scope.cants[j].quantity;
  } else if ($scope.cants[j].type === "sauces") {       
    $scope.sauces += $scope.cants[j].quantity;
  } 
  $scope.componentsPlate = $scope.proteins +  $scope.veggies + $scope.sauces +     $scope.dryfruits + $scope.bases + $scope.proteinsExtra +        $scope.veggiesExtra + $scope.saucesExtra + $scope.dryfruitsExtra +  $scope.basesExtra
}
```

Comment: Cual es el scope de las variables que necesitas crear? Estan dentro de una funcion, las necesitas globalmente? Estas dentro de un navegador y pueden estar dentro de window?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz, en  una función

Comment: Ojo es importare decir que no es buena idea hacer esto para un programa real, ya que dará problemas para leer el código y su depuración a futuro.

Comment: Y por casulidad como piensas usar luego esas variables? Te funciona si no son variables sino propiedades dentro de una variable inicializada al comienzo de la función?

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz como propiedades no me sirven

Comment: @WilfredoP lo se pero es por el performace de la app, ademas si se logra  quedara documentado el algoritmo utilizado

Comment: Puedes crear el código que has intentado para tenerlo como referencia y poder completarlo o corregirlo? Además nos podrías explicar que es lo que estás tratando de hacer? Es posible que haya alguna otra solución más fácil

Comment: @DanielHernández yo creo que es mejor que coloques todo el contexto de la pregunta, con algo de código para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Tu  código sigue sin esclarecer la pregunta – desde mi punto de vista. Sigo sin saber por qué pretendes hacer esto, aquí tratamos de ayudar a la gente en nuestros ratos libres, no descifrar el código que escriben; recuerda que lo hacemos gratuitamente.

Comment: Explica tu código y tus motivos para llevar a cabo tal práctica, o de lo contrario me veré obligado a marcar tu pregunta como poco clara para la revisión de la comunidad.

Comment: @JuanRocamonde listo ya edite la pregunta

Comment: Yo también edite mi pregunta, échale un vistazo

Comment: @JuanRocamonde el codigo de mi pregunta funciona, pero en realidad son 150 else if, quiero saber si hay manera de reducirlo

Comment: @DanielHernández ahora todo tiene sentido. Creo que estabas confundiendo el concepto de *variable* con *miembro de un objeto*

Comment: La respuesta de @CarlosMuñoz debería servirte para lo que quieres. En tu caso que sea legible el programa no es tan importante ya que al parecer estas usando angular y en tu caso que el `scope` tenga las propiedades correctas es lo importante para que el binding funcione. Angular es "noble" haciendo binding asi que bindear a una propiedad que no existe no genera error. Tener 150 condiciones en un `controller` es peor que un simple algoritmo de 3 líneas con un comentario que explique su funcionamiento.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La sintaxis:

```
$scope.nombreDePropiedad
```

Es equivalente a:

```
$scope["nombreDePropiedad"]
```

Lo cual puedes aprovechar para utilizarlo de la sgte forma:

```
for (var j = 0; j < $scope.cants.length; j++) {
    $scope[$scope.cants[j].type] += $scope.cants[j].quantity;
}
```

De esta manera no necesitas hacer ningún `if` o `switch` ya que el miembro correcto del objeto `$scope` será seleccionado a partir del string que le pases entre corchetes.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pretendes hacer es totalmente contrario a lo que se recomienda hacer.

El objetivo de almacenar datos en variables con un nombre fijo en un `namespace` es referirse a ellas cuando sea preciso conociendo el nombre de la variable.

Cuando el nombre asignado al dato no se conoce, se emplean los diccionarios (`arrays`) en que se pasa el nombre asociado al tipo de esto que se pretende usar, en caso de que éste se encuentre almacenado en una variable y no se conozca su nombre *a priori*.

Lo que tú pretendes hacer no es solo poco recomendable, además de inmantenible al escalar el código, sino que va contra los principios de la programación — lo que debes hacer es replantearte cómo debes estructurar tus datos, para mejorar la legibilidad y calidad de tu código.

Si nos comentas por qué pretendes usar variables a toda costa, quizá podamos ayudarte, pero sin más aclaraciones, estas son mis recomendaciones.

**Edición posterior**

Visto tu problema, la solución planteada en la otra respuesta es la mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Quizas usted pueda barajar la posibilidada de usar un `switch`, dado que usted menciona que son unos `150 casos`, creo que el uso del `switch` mejor el rendimiento con respecto a `150 casos`, si fueran unos poco quizas esto no se notaria pero para 150 me plantearia el uso del switch.

Por otro lado si usted decide usar `if else`, intentaria situar los casos mas comunes al principio del `if`.

P.D: Usted dice reducir el algoritmo, no se si tambien incluye el hacer cambios para la eficiencia del mismo

Comment: El problema no es de sintaxis, sino de implementación

Comment: @JuanRocamonde de acuerdo borro la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: No es necesario, simplemente aclaro para los lectores. Puede servir de ayuda.